# How to retrieve varchar data in table ex: '2012/05/01 09:42'

Tags: sql, oracle, record, varchar

I have few data in Intime table like  2012/05/01 09:41
2012/05/05 09:47
2012/05/07 08:30
2012/05/09 08:45
2012/05/10 09:41,

Since I want the data like greater than 2012/05/01 09:30 query will be like

select Intime from table where Intime>2012/05/01 09:30 its fetching only the 2012/05/01 not 09:30 the datatype of Intime is varchar2

Comment: You havn't said which language and system you are asking about.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 oracle database and jsp

Comment: If the datatype of  Intime  is varchar2 then firstly your where clause will not evaluate with out single quotes. Secondly there might me every possibilty that the result set would have no time with it. Check out if the coulmn has the data in which you specified.

Comment: Never ever store dates as `VARCHAR`. Fix your data model **now**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your `varchar2` column to `date` and then do your comparison. You need to use it this way:

```
SELECT TO_DATE (Intime, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI') D_ATE
FROM TABLE    
WHERE to_date(Intime ,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI') > to_date('2012/05/01 09:30','YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI');
```

Demo:

```
 with dt_tbl (Intime) as ( select '2012/05/01 09:30' from dual
                         UNION ALL
                         select '2012/05/01 09:42' from dual
                         UNION ALL
                         select '2012/05/01 09:29' from dual
                         UNION ALL
                         select '2012/05/01 09:35' from dual)
SELECT TO_DATE (Intime, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI') D_ATE
FROM dt_tbl    
WHERE to_date(Intime ,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI') > to_date('2012/05/01 09:30','YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI');
```

Comment: To_date function converts the varchar to date. read more http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm